# How to invoke a character in java?

Tags: java

How to do it without char c = scanner.next().charAt(0)
as I didn't learn how to use 'At' and read function invokes only one character while I want it to read the entire line.

Comment: Define "invoke a character". Make your question clear. If you want to read an entire line from a Scanner, then call nextLine(). The javadoc is your friend.

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you want to read a **line** why don't you use `nextLine()` then?

Comment: guys nextLine() is for a string and invoke a character means that the user has to give the character

Comment: By "invoke" do you mean "Get a character from user input"?

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches can be: read the line using `nextLine()` and store it in a `String` and then use `charAt()` something like:

```
String line = reader.nextLine();
char c = line.charAt(0);
```